# Suggestions on a lazy indexed vector in C++11?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, managed-c++

I am working with a lot of objects and many of those objects have arrays of sub objects.   Some of these can have millions of items, and during specific operations, I need the items to be accessed by name.

But, at the same time, I need to keep performance and memory consumption low.  So my thought was to create a composite template class something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
class IndexedList {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> items;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>> index;
    void build_index();
};
```

For the lists where the item names are unique, this is ok, but where I am struggling is how to deal with lists where the names are not unique.   I can't really use a map, and I would rather not iterate over the set.

The other point is that I have to get the items back in the same order on some instances and in a sorted order in another.

So, the challenge is can it be done with a single template?   I would prefer not to have to decide at compile time which method to use.   Ideally something like a SmartList, that lazily indexes once the item list is loaded and decides at runtime if it should use a map or unordered_map (or set) based on the load pattern when searches by name begin coming in.   It should also handle multiple keys values, if multiple were encountered during the load of the vector.

Anyone have such a beast?

Comment: Not an answer, but something to consider - if you want to address them by name instead of index, how do you expect to find the actual object you are looking for when the names are identical? Throw an exception and force by-index lookup? Return all possible elements with the name given? A lookup key can only work perfectly when uniqueness is enforced.

Comment: There is too much verbiage here. You need to access by what mostly? And by name sometimes?

Comment: Perhaps you could keep the items in their current container, and instead use a `std::map< std::string, std::list<[container]::iterator> >` to index/reference the elements of the container? Have to be careful not to invalidate the iterators, though...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
template <typename T>
class IndexedList
{
  public:
    std::vector<T> items;
    std::multimap<std::string, std::vector<T>::size_type> index;
    void build_index();
};
```

...where the `mutlimap` is tolerant of duplicate `string` keys, and stores indices in the `vector` (which will not be invalidated by `vector` resizing during `push_back`/`emplace_back`s).

If there's some way in which this doesn't meet your requirements, please explain....

Comment: Cool!   I was not aware of multimap.    It looks promising.   Let me check that out and see if it will work.   Thanks.